# Commit git submodule in a parent module

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, git-remote

I git cloned a public project (read-only)

and I changed some code of it.

and then, I would like to upload it in my private git just for storing.

**SUMMARY**

I want to make my private git repo which includes a public read-only project edited by myself.

Comment: You can fork the public project and do as you like with your fork. You can also simply create a git repository and push your files to it (you will have to change the url as described here: [how-to-change-git-remote-url/](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-change-git-remote-url/)). I don't see what your question has to do with sub modules.

Comment: Thank you @topsail. 'git' fork was the thing that I need. But I cannot understand why do I change the url.

Comment: With forking, no you don't need to change any urls. So you have two options - Option One - to create your own completely independent repository and just use the files from the original repository as your starting point (as in Ruffalo's answer below). In this case you *might* need to change the url to get it pointed to the right (new) repository.  Option Two - to use a fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

```
$ git remote add your_private_repo http://github.com/yourname/private_repo.git
```

check it !

```
$ git remote -v
# origin http://github.com/target/public_repo.git
# your_private_repo http://github.com/yourname/private_repo.git
```

and

```
$ git push your_private_repo your_branch
```

The biggest fear of the `Git` is that multiple remote addresses can be applied if the base is the same code.

Comment: OMG Extremely helpful! Thanks @Ruffalo! But then what if there's new version of public_repo and I want to merge it edited private_repo?

Comment: *what if there's new version of public_repo and I want to merge it edited private_repo* -- in this case forking the repo is what you want as you can "update" it with new changes in the "parent" repository.  If you create a new repository of your own and push the files to it after downloading or cloning the other repository, then your copy is "static" and essentially completely independent of the parent - probably there are ways to merge things at that point but not as easy as just using a simple git merge or git pull command as you could do with a forked repository.

Comment: @topsail Oh alright, so basically `remote` goes with `clone`, which means static. And `fork` is dynamic. Also, `fork` is my private_repo so it does not need `remote` stuff.

Comment: You can probably use `git merge`. However, it may conflict with the content of your private repository, so you need to resolve it properly.